# C# nested stream with using statement, should I use two using?

Tags: c#, stream, using, memorystream

I'm writing a piece of code which uses nested stream:

```
using (var zip = new ZlibStream(new MemoryStream(to_be_unziped), CompressionMode.Decompress))
{

}
```

Is it fine? Or should I write it as:

```
using (var memory_stream = new MemoryStream(to_be_unziped))
using (var zip = new ZlibStream(memory_stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{

}
```

Comment: For readability I use the second one. Technical there is no difference between both versions

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the 1st method, but I think 2nd one is more readable
but in the second one it should be just `memory_stream` not `var memory_stream`

Comment: @TheLastStark Oh it's my typo. I've fixed it.

Comment: So in the 1st method, when the outer stream gets closed, the inner one will also be closed, right?

Comment: Ok cool, I would prefer to write more readable code as where possible so I would've gone with 2nd method, but the 1st one is not that hard to read as well.

Comment: @OgrishMan yes, it will run out of scope as well

Comment: You don't need to dispose MemoryStream.

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments! Could anyone write an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @TheLastStark It will be disposed by ZlibStream instance - you had to set leaveOpen argument to true if you do not want it

Comment: @SirRufo it will get disposed along with `ZlibStream` right? not before?

Comment: @TheLastStark Yes, because it is done by ZlibStream

Comment: Yeah exactly, that's what I meant earlier too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a `ZlibStream` and pass in `MemoryStream` it holds a reference to it.

When it's `Disposed`, it calls `Close` on that reference, which in turn will hit the `Dispose` plumbing of *abstract* `Stream` class.

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    try
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing && (this._baseStream != null))
                this._baseStream.Close();
            _disposed = true;
        }
     }
     finally
     {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
     }
}
```

It's worth noting, that a `MemoryStream` has no unmanaged resources anyway, and actually doesn't need to be *Disposed*, it doesn't *override* the `Close` of the `Stream` class.

`Stream` also checks if `Dispose` has already been called. Meaning in most cases, you only have to `Dispose` the *stream* you are working with.